# Android JNI c++ files compiling

Tags: eclipse, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI in Android development. I want to know where do the compiler find the referenced .h files?

Here in `jni/jni_part.cpp`, it includs lots of .h files. Opencv related files are defined by the SDK, but the "cartoon.h" is sure to be a project-specified header. But I cannot find it in the project folder. Then do the eclipse compile the JNI c++ code at every run? If so , in which directories does the eclipse find these headers?

Maybe it's basic for JNI but I'm not familiar with it. So plz help me out with one or two sentences. Or you could just paste a simple tutorial for JNI in Android, eclipse.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>


#include "cartoon.h"
#include "ImageUtils.h" // Handy functions for debugging OpenCV images, by Shervin Emami.


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {

.....
```

This is my eclipse project folder structure

```
/project
  /jni
    jni_part.cpp
  /src
    something.java
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to start using android-ndk to compile the .c, .cpp files to a .so library object, which you can then use in your android project.

Please refer to the Android NDK to get started.
http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#GetStarted

you can find examples in the NDK download.

Answer (score 0):

If Eclipse "knows" where `cartoon.h` file is on disk, it will help you find it - put the cursor on that `#include` line and press **F3**.

Regarding your other question: Eclipse compiles only if the relevant files (sources, headers, or mk) change.

Comment: THX. But how does the Eclipse know it? Which directories does it search in? Besides, the Eclipse mark all those things as errors, so I'm not sure if Eclipse knows where they are at least at this time.

Comment: I am sorry, I took your word for it... You wrote that Eclipse knows where the files are. If **F3** does not work on `cartoon.h` file, what exactly _does_ work? If build succeeds, you can look into **jni/Android.mk** file for clues.

Comment: It is me to say sorry, for my poor English. I updated my words to "in which directoris does the eclipse search for the headers."

Comment: @SolessCHong, does the **F3** button bring you to the file or not? If it does, then you can see the file path. If it does not, then your question is irrelevant: the file is not in one of the directories that eclipse searches. Anyways, eclipse is not responsible for build logic, it only starts the **ndk-build** script.